# How to make Carousel Bootstrap 3 responsive

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Hello I create Carousel using Bootstrap 3, and I add 4 images inside it.
When I resize browser, the images are stack.
I want show just 2 images when resize it in mobile mode, or whatever the best fit.

Here is my code :

```
...
<!-- Wrapper for slides -->
<div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <div class="item active">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-3 center"><img src="assets/images/prodlogo_1.png" alt="..."></div>
            <div class="col-sm-3 center"><img src="assets/images/prodlogo_1.png" alt="..."></div>
            <div class="col-sm-3 center"><img src="assets/images/prodlogo_1.png" alt="..."></div>
            <div class="col-sm-3 center"><img src="assets/images/prodlogo_1.png" alt="..."></div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="item">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-3 center"><img src="assets/images/prodlogo_1.png" alt="..."></div>
            <div class="col-sm-3 center"><img src="assets/images/prodlogo_1.png" alt="..."></div>
            <div class="col-sm-3 center"><img src="assets/images/prodlogo_1.png" alt="..."></div>
            <div class="col-sm-3 center"><img src="assets/images/prodlogo_1.png" alt="..."></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
...
```

Here is my screenshot when resize it :
[image: Carousel in Small width]

How to fix that? Thank you

Comment: on the divs you want to hide add the class `hidden-xs`

Comment: But it still vertically stack. How to make horizontal? ^^

Comment: you are using the `sm-3` class, then on `xs` it's like 12 for default .... you can add to those elements the class `col-xs-6` keeping two aside :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is unfortunately not possible with bootstrap. If you put `hidden-xs` on carousel items, they will be excluded from the carousel.

Here is a jQuery plugin that will help out: http://owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/index.html

Comment: hey i already try this. And its good plugin ^^ thank you very much.